# How to open a file in netbeans from another ubuntu machine?

Tags: ubuntu, java

I have files in a Ubuntu server that I want to open in Netbeans.

I wonder how I can do that?

Im running Mac os x.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mount the remote volume and search your files under /Volumes/ (MacOsX)

Comment: what do i have to do in Ubuntu to be able to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Mount the remote path in nautilus, then look for it under `~/.gvfs/`.

Comment: My local machine is running Mac OS X. The remote server is running Ubuntu. So I have no Nautilus installed.

Comment: @ajsie: And you didn't think that would be important to mention?